# Does 2.1 XML version work with Sage Intacct AJAX?

Tags: xml, sage, intacct

I am working on a program that takes a users CVS file, and populates into a table while calculating the dollar amount then on submit the data table values will be sent using AJAX API. The problem that I am having is the create_sotransaction is a object-specific function which is a 2.1 XML version. My guess is that version does not work with AJAX, but need community support.

```
<script>
    `function createBeforeSubmit(){
        console.log("Within the function"); 
        var fieldsArray = {
            'transaction_type': 'Sales Invoice',
            'datecreated' : {
                'year': '2024', 
                'month': '3', 
                'day': '20' 
            }, 
            'customerid': jq('#MY_CUSTOMER').val(),
            'state': 'Pending', 
            'sotransitems': {
                'sotransitem': {
                    'itemid': jq('#MY_ITEM').val(),
                    'price': jq('#MY_Amount').val(),
                    'quantity': 1,
                    'locationid': jq('#My_Revenue').val(),
                    'departmentid': jq('#MY_Department').val(),
                }
            }
        }
        var api = new API_Session(); 
        var callback = function(responseText){
            console.log(responseText)
        }
        api.ip_create('create_sotransactions', fieldsArray, callback);`
    }
 
</script>
```

outcome: The values of the inputs will go into a Sales Invoice with the correct objects.